# информация про объект google maps api

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Ребята помогите пожалуйста с Google maps api, мне нужно узнать информацию про объект, например если это кафешка или ресторан то в сколько открытие\закрытие, я не уверен что это можно сделать, потому что не смог найти никакой информации, помогите плиз

Comment: смотрите google place api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

здесь есть все что вам нужно)

[image: Google Maps API]